# The difference between __str__ and __repr__?

Tags: python

I write this code:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name;
    def __str__(self):
        return "Item: %s" % self._name
```

When I run

```
print((Item("Car"),))
```

the output is

```
(<__main__.Item object at 0x0000000002D32400>,)
```

When I change the code to this:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name;
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Item: %s" % self._name
    def __str__(self):
        return "Item: %s" % self._name
```

it then outputs

```
(Item: Car,)
```

So now I am confused about the difference between `__repr__` and `__str__`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`__str__` and `__repr__` are both methods for getting a string representation of an object. `__str__` is supposed to be shorter and more user-friendly, while `__repr__` is supposed to provide more detail.

Specifically, for many data types, `__repr__` returns a string that, if you pasted it back into Python, would be a valid expression whose value would be equal to the original value. For instance, `str('Hello')` returns `'Hello'`, but `repr('Hello')` returns `"'Hello'"`, with quote marks inside the string. If you printed that string out, you'd get `'Hello'`, and if you pasted that back into Python, you'd get the original string back.

Some data types, like file objects, can't be converted to strings this way. The `__repr__` methods of such objects usually return a string in angle brackets that includes the object's data type and memory address. User-defined classes also do this if you don't specifically define the `__repr__` method.

When you compute a value in the REPL, Python calls `__repr__` to convert it into a string. When you use `print`, however, Python calls `__str__`.

When you call `print((Item("Car"),))`, you're calling the `__str__` method of the `tuple` class, which is the same as its `__repr__` method. That method works by calling the `__repr__` method of each item in the tuple, joining them together with commas (plus a trailing one for a one-item tuple), and surrounding the whole thing with parentheses. I'm not sure why the `__str__` method of `tuple` doesn't call `__str__` on its contents, but it doesn't.

Comment: Beat me to it! :) http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__

Comment: You beat me to it as well! However, it would be useful to add a note that `__repr__` is usually expected to be a statement that would reproduce the object.  From the docs: "this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value".

Comment: ...And I realized that I completely missed the actual point of the question. Fixed.

Comment: A small example: `from datetime import datetime as dt; dt.today().__str__(); dt.today().__repr__()`